# How to append values returned by a function in a Set?

Tags: python, function, set

I have written a code, which updates the value returned by two sets(tag_coordinates,tag_id) from a function in to a single set(required_info). When i am trying to print the value in required_info, the value is printed twice and the elements in the set are not ordered.

```
def GetLabels(taginfo):      #this function gets the value taginfo, from an another code
    tag_coordinates = set()  #set to update tag_coordinates
    tag_id = set()           #set to update tag_id
    required_info = set()    #set to update required_info
    r=60
    for (tag,xy,orient,err,wl,sq) in taginfo:
        xy2= (int(xy[0]+r*math.sin(math.radians(orient))),int(xy[1]-r*math.cos(math.radians(orient))))
        tag_coordinates.add(xy) #corresponding tag_coordinates
        tag_id.add(tag)         #corresponding tag_id
        required_info.update(tag_coordinates,tag_id)
        print required_info
```

Now once i print required_info, i will get a set printed twice, with corresponding values from the set tag_coordinates,tag_id not arranged together. Any suggestions?

Comment: set doesn't have to be ordered in math and so it is in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but if you wanted a set of pairs (tag, coordinates)

```
def get_labels(taginfo):
    return {
        (tag, calc_coordinates(x, y, orient))
        for tag, (x, y), orient, *_ in taginfo
    }


def calc_coordinates(x, y, orient):
    orient_rad = 60 * math.radians(orient)
    return int(x + math.sin(orient_rad)), int(y - math.cos(orient_rad))
```

If one tagid can have multiple cooridantes then you can use groupby

`groupby(operator.itemgetter(0), get_labels(taginfo))` which would group coordinates by tag.

`get_labels` is just `GetLabels` but in PEP8 compliant notation. Functions should have small letters and be in snake_case instead of CamelCase.

`calc_coordinates` is just a function extracted from this line

```
xy2= (int(xy[0]+r*math.sin(math.radians(orient))),int(xy[1]-r*math.cos(math.radians(orient))))
```

Again, it's wasn't PEP8 compliant and readability was not that good.
`orient_sin` is just a temp variable to improve peformance and readability. Since I don't know the domain I've probably given it ugly name, but you can improve it.

`get_labels` returns a set of pairs (tag_id, coordinates). It's defined via set comprehension feature of python.

Comment: I am not able to understand what you have provided. Can you give some comments ? What i am trying to achieve in code is to get the set of pairs of (tag_coordinates , tag_id ) together. I am able to achieve it the code mentioned above. But same value is getting printed twice.

Comment: @George luke I get what `set of pairs (tag_id, tag_coordinates)` mean. What I don't understand is what you mean by `together`.

Comment: what i mean is the tag_coordinates corresponding to tag_id.

Comment: Well, then I think the code in my answer does what you need. I uses set comprehension and iterable unpacking in `tag, (x, y), orient, *_`. `*_` will be the tuple with the rest of elements from taginfo. It's just a way to say that you don't care about that part.

Comment: If one `tag_id` can have more than one `tag_coordinates` then you can use a groupby.

Comment: @user168095, Can you tell me what get_labels, calc_coordinates, (x,y), orient_sin means? Because i don't have them defined in my code.

Comment: I've tried to explain what this code does, but you better be more specific about what you don't understand. For example `orient_sin` - do you don't why it's named this way or do you don't get how it's calculated or what?

Comment: @do the 'get_labels' in your code means 'GetLabels' in mycode? the coordinates are provided by (xy) in my code do u mean the same by (x,y)? Also what is the condition after for loop?

Comment: @Georgeluke `get_labels` supposedly doing the same as `GetLabels`. Read the updated answer. `(x,y)` is iterable unpacking and should be the same as `xy`. There is no condition after the for loop, so I don't know what you mean.